# Is there a way to write "http://" in a shortcut way in HTML

Tags: html, shortcut

So i'm on a website with a caracter limitator and i would love to pass multiple links. HTML is on !
Is there a way to write for example http://google.com with a shortcut like 
./google.com ?

Thanks à lot

Comment: `//www.google.com` is a valid *protocol relative* URL, of course host and target protocols must match.

Comment: Are you referring to the url in an html tag such as `<a>` or `<img>`?

Comment: Maybe the best way would be to create a blog post with all the links you want, then to post a link to your blog entry, that way you will only need to include one link in the character limited site.

Comment: You are "on a website"? Meaning you have some web application that allows you to enter a text using a form? In that case you might want to tell us what web application you use. BTW: this doesn't seem to be a topic for stack overflow if it's about filling forms on some website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding only `//` in front of the link will work just fine, and actually it helps to inclue both `http` and `https` links, something like

```html
<a href="//example.com">I am a Link</a>
```

Comment: FANTASTIC ! THANK YOU THAT WAS EXACTLY FOR THAT PURPOSE !

Answer (score 1):

You can put both www.google.com or google.com as either is accepted as a valid URL by browsers. The only difference would be if the address used the secure https protocol and then https:// would be needed, otherwise leave it off.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply put `google.com`; assuming you have a modern browser, it will figure out that you mean `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: not sure this is correct.  if you create an anchor as `<a href="google.com">google</a>` your browser will interpret that as a page relative url and try to navigate to it as such.